# How to add element dynamically in Modal popup without clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

How to add element in modal popup body. like

```
<div class="custom-modal modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"></div>
</div>

<select id="divCar">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How to can add `divCar` without clone() or getting html(). Becuase i dont want multiple `id="divCar"` on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use remove the `id` using [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) after making a [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)

```
var modalContent = $("#divCar").clone().removeAttr('id');
$(".modal-body").append(modalContent);
```

Comment: I think he said without `clone`

Comment: but every time need to append again in the DOM.

Comment: @SAL if you want the same [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) element at two places, I don't know if that's even possible without cloning. As far as the issue with `id`, my solution handles that. And it wouldn't change the original DOM element. By your question it seems you didn't want `clone` because of duplicate `id`'s...

Answer (score 0):

So you want the element to be moved into the modal, not to be cloned. With the use of jQuery you can move an element with

```
var element = $("#divCar");
element.detach();
$(".modal-body").append(element);
```

Comment: Dont want to remove element. just pull to popup and when close it should remain their